# How to validate the textbox inside echo?

Tags: php, forms

I'm trying that validating the text box inside echo in php. I tried some methods but it is not working.

php form code:

```
 echo '<form method="post" action="singlepage.php?id='.$idn.'"';
 echo '<label id="blogtextarea2">Comment:</label><textarea rows="10" cols="75" name="comment" id="blogtextarea" ></textarea><br>';
 echo '<input type="submit" name="post" id="blogsubmit" value="post">';
 echo '</form>';
```

and validation code is

```
if(isset($_POST['post']))
 {
if ($_POST['comment'] != "") {
        $_POST['comment'] = filter_var($_POST['comment'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        if ($_POST['comment'] == "") {
            $errors .= 'Please enter a valid name.<br/><br/>';
        }
    } else {
        $errors= 'Please enter your name.<br/>';
    }
  }
```

Comment: not working, so u see blue screen? Or what? Debug your code, if dont know how, use var_dump and die() everywhere

Comment: You are passing an id through a query string but using a post method. Should be GET!!  Otherwise just make the post method: singlepage.php

Comment: @Hexana 's answer is only relevant if you wish to use the id in your code/validation, otherwise, you are retrieving the post data correctly through $_POST. Regardless, please provide what you are trying to achieve so we can more clearly provide you with some relevant answers. Perhaps an expected output?

Comment: @shrmn i need an simple empty validation for the text box using $_POST method in form.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it why it is not working

```
if(isset($_POST['post']))
{
    if (!empty($_POST['comment'])) {
        $_POST['comment'] = filter_var($_POST['comment'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    } else {
        $errors = 'Please enter your name.';
    }
}   
echo $errors;
```

You have to check defined conditions on singlepage.php

Comment: what is your expected result ?

Comment: i need an simple empty validation for the text box using $_POST method in form.

Comment: code above is working also validation , if nothing is enter in textarea and you press post then error will occur also as you action defined is singlepage.php page so error check is on that page.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you meant by "not working", but I have cleaned up your code and changed the check for an empty POST comment data using the empty() function instead.

There was also a redundant check within your first check for an empty comment which I've removed:

```
$errors = '';
if(isset($_POST['post'])) {
    if(!empty($_POST['comment'])) {
        $_POST['comment'] = filter_var($_POST['comment'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    } else {
        $errors = 'Please enter your name.<br/>';
    }
}
echo $errors;
```